# Most reliable way to find already existing program in Linux using shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, installation, uninstallation

I am installing a Java GUI application with few jars and related resource in linux in some directory.
The install script is written using bash script. If I try to execute the same script then the same application is installed in some other location.
What is the correct way to avoid multiple installation. I want to identify the already existing program regardless of the user.

Comment: you should try https://unix.stackexchange.com/ for this.

Comment: Your install script installs programs in different locations on different runs without the user explicitly requesting that?

Comment: @Shawn , your inputs the install location

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like this:

```
compgen -c | grep "your program name"
```

Compgen gives out all commands and paths